# How to add checkbox into FormLayout (Vaadin)

Tags: java, checkbox, vaadin, form-layout

I am trying to add the `checkbox` into the `FormLayout`, but it throwing an warning:

My code

```
private void createEditorLayout(SplitLayout splitLayout) {

    Div editorLayoutDiv = new Div();
    editorLayoutDiv.setClassName("editor-layout");

    Div editorDiv = new Div();
    editorDiv.setClassName("editor");
    editorLayoutDiv.add(editorDiv);

    FormLayout formLayout = new FormLayout();
    monthAndYear = new DatePicker("Month and year");
    organizationId = new TextField("Organiziation ID");
    userId = new TextField("User ID");
    onlyForOrganization = new Checkbox("Only for organization");

    Component[] fields = new Component[]{monthAndYear, onlyForOrganization, organizationId, userId}; 

    formLayout.add(fields);
    editorDiv.add(formLayout);
    createButtonLayout(editorLayoutDiv);
    splitLayout.addToSecondary(editorLayoutDiv);

}
```

The problematic is this row:

```
Component[] fields = new Component[]{monthAndYear, onlyForOrganization, organizationId, userId};
```

It showing warning:

```
Required type: Component
Provided: Checkbox
```

Is it possible to somehow add a checkbox to the `FormLayout`?

Comment: What do you mean by "it showing warning" - what is "it"? Has the warning any relevance? Are you using the correct checkbox (e.g. the one from Vaadin and not the one from Swing)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you are importing the wrong Checkbox. Make sure the import is `com.vaadin.flow.component.checkbox.Checkbox`.

Comment: quick, short,  but correct answer. well thank you!